# Excel is missing some values while writing

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am new to Apache-poi and using 3.8 version of poi.  While writing value in the Excel,i check for the column names if they matched, i will write some value in that column and finish it, and again i will start writing on header. The problem is if write three column values only last column values are add or saved and first two values are not saved in the column. Can anyone tell what went wrong.
    (sorry, in case any mistake)

```
 Code:
            int i = 0;
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_ORANGE.index);
        String validate_header = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (eiterator.hasNext()) {
                validate_header = eiterator.next();
            }
            Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
            String col_heading = iterator.next();
            cell.setCellValue(col_heading);
            if(col_heading.equalsIgnoreCase("Assigned Date"))
            {
                Add_value(i, col_heading, row, sheet);
                row=sheet.getRow(0);
                cell=row.getCell(i);
            }
            else if(col_heading.startsWith("Review"))
            {
                int count=-1;
                int n=Col_values.get("Defect Summary").size();
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                            row = sheet.createRow(count);
                    cell = row.createCell(i);
                    String s="External QC Defect ";     
                    cell.setCellValue(s);
                    count++;

                }
                row=sheet.getRow(0);
                cell=row.getCell(i);

            }

            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
            i++;

        }

private static Sheet Add_value(int k,String name,Row row, Sheet sheet) {

        System.out.println("Inside the add method");


        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Assigned Date")||name.equalsIgnoreCase("Reported Date") )
        {
        vector = Col_values.get("TargetDate");
        int count = 1;

        System.out.println("IF Size of the vector  " + vector.size());
        for (int j = 0; j < vector.size(); j++) {

            row = sheet.createRow(count);
            cell = row.createCell(k);
            String s = (String) vector.get(j);
            System.out.println(s);
            cell.setCellValue(s);
            count++;

        }
        }
        else
        {
        vector = Col_values.get("Defect Summary");
            int count = 1;
    System.out.println("ELSE Size of the vector  " + vector.size());
        for (int j = 0; j < vector.size(); j++) {

            row = sheet.createRow(count);
            cell = row.createCell(k);
            String s = (String) vector.get(j);
            System.out.println(s);
            cell.setCellValue(s);
            count++;
        }
        }
        return sheet;

    }
```

'

Can u tell what went Wrong?

Comment: where is code? how we know where are you wrong???

Comment: Sorry. I have added now.

Comment: Simply rewrite the code from scratch: it has too many open ends (iterator) and too many local purposes (use of createRow). It would also be better to follow Java conventions (i.e. for acceptance here): more use of spaces, `camelCaseNames` i.o. `Capitalized_underscored_ones`. You could use top-down design with small functions for a specific purpose. _I understand the reason: first experiments with ugly POI._

Comment: But it work fine.. even it looks ugly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Add_value` starts creating rows from top. Therefore on the second call the old rows are removed.

Replace

```
         row = sheet.createRow(count);
```

with

```
         row = k == 0 ? sheet.createRow(count) : sheet.getRow(count);
```

Comment: No, It seems the count has been incremented after creating the cell for that particular row. i need to insert value in vertically not horizontally.

Comment: It does not function that way. Conceptually a sheet is row[] and a row is cell[]. You could try out-commenting other createRows and try my code.